# Batch script doesn't function properly

Tags: batch-file, 7zip

So this is what I have so far. The problem I'm having is it archives the file to 7zip and when I try to tell it to move this file it says it's not there. I'm not sure if there's an easier way to move, zip, and rename a file and move it again to another folder.

```
@Echo Off
xcopy "\\READYSHARE\USB_Storage\Address Book\Address Book" "C:\Users\Service Department\Desktop\Zip" 
7za a –tzip "C:\Users\Service Department\Desktop\ZIpped" "C:\Users\Service Department\Desktop\Zip" /s /e
pause
```

Comment: Which line is your error occurring on?

Comment: 7za a –tzip "C:\Users\Service Department\Desktop\ZIpped" "C:\Users\Service Department\Desktop\Zip" /s /e
pause    this creates a zip named ûtzip and when i run another batch file to rename it it says its not there so im wondering if theres a way to tell it name it while it zips ive tested the other batch file and it works to rename other stuff just not that file

Comment: What are `/s` and `/e` supposed to do?  7zip uses hyphen-based arguments, not slash based.  Also you are **already** telling 7za the filename while it zips... you've told it "C:\Users\Service Department\Desktop\ZIpped".

Answer (score 0):

It is always advisable to read the documentation of the commands to use before creating a batch file.

- [xcopy](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/xcopy.mspx) (Microsoft Windows XP documenation, easier to read) or [xcopy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771254.aspx) (Microsoft TechNet article)
- Documentation for 7-Zip standalone command line tool `7za` is installed together with 7-Zip in program files folder of 7-Zip. The file to view is `7-zip.chm`, a Windows help file.

The switches `/s` and `/e` belong to command `xcopy`, but are appended to call of `7za`. `/s` is for copying also subdirectories, but not empty subdirectories. `/e` is for copying also subdirectories including empty subdirectories. It is possible to specify both, but usually just `/e` needs to be specified to copy a directory tree completely using `xcopy`.

To recursively archive all files and folders of a folder with `7za` the switch `-r` must be used according to 7-Zip documentation.

```
@echo off
%SystemRoot%\System32\xcopy.exe "\\READYSHARE\USB_Storage\Address Book\Address Book" "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Zip" /E /I
"%ProgramFiles%\7-Zip\7za.exe" a –tzip "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Zipped.zip" -r "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Zip"
pause
```

I have not executed this batch file, but it should work if path to `7za.exe` is correct on your computer.